# Tcp Socket Program for UWP

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, uwp, tcplistener

I am having a capsule game object created in unity and I have written a TCP socket program to connect with a python script. The code was working fine as long as it is running for PC/Linux targets. But when i try to build it for the UWP application using Universal 10/D3D build settings it gives compile error that TcpListener class is not found. I have tried to fix this issue using comipler #if-#else statements, but as I am new to UWP programming and APIs, getting a lot of trouble figuruing out how can I convert my existing code to work with UWP APIs.

Please suggest the changes required in my code or some easy workaround.
The Code :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
// Required for socket programming
using System.IO;

#if NETFX_CORE
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
#else
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
#endif

using System.Text;

public class capsule : MonoBehaviour {

    public left lft;
    public right rht;


    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

    #if NETFX_CORE
        Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener myList = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();
    #else
        TcpListener myList;
    #endif

    #if NETFX_CORE
        Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket s = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
    #else
        Socket s;
    #endif

    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    String str_msgs, str_cmd, str_val;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        #if NETFX_CORE
            Debug.Log("The server is running at port 3085..." + Environment.NewLine);

            Debug.Log("Waiting for a connection..." + Environment.NewLine);

            await s.ConnectAsync(ipAd, 3085)
        #else
            myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 3085);
            myList.Start();

            Debug.Log("The server is running at port 3085..." + Environment.NewLine);

            Debug.Log("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint + Environment.NewLine);

            Debug.Log("Waiting for a connection..." + Environment.NewLine);

            s = myList.AcceptSocket();

        #endif

        Debug.Log("Connection accepted " + s.RemoteEndPoint + Environment.NewLine);

        #if NETFX_CORE

            // To do something

        #else

            int k = s.Receive(b);

            Debug.Log("Recieved..." + Environment.NewLine);

            str_msgs = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);

            Array.Clear(b, 0, b.Length);

            Debug.Log(str_msgs + Environment.NewLine);

            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("Sent: Connected with server." + Environment.NewLine));

            Debug.Log(Environment.NewLine + "Sent Acknowledgement !" + Environment.NewLine);
        #endif
    }
```

How can i Accept the socket connection using UWP and send and receive data the way i am doing using Sockets class. Screenshot of error is attached here which i am getting during the build.

[Build Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjH9b.jpg)

Comment: Is NETFX_CORE true? TcpListener is in library System.Net.Sockets.

Comment: yes , but the whole problem is it is not getting detected when i am building project for windows platform Universal 10 (UWP) it is not detecting the Systems.Net.Sockets class at all.

Comment: What version of Net Library is selected in the Project?  Try Net 4.5 or earlier.